Riemann Integral and Rational Numbers

Hello,
I am self-studying real analysis and I am unable to solve this very interesting question I came across.
I am not fully sure why the upper Darboux sum for this function is equal to 0. The argument for the lower Darboux sum for this function, and non-Riemann integrability of the point-wise convergence of this sequence of functions is quite straight forward; however, I would really appreciate some help with the upper Darboux sum (I think we have to use the enumeration part of this question)
Thanks in advance!

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here are some of the reasons why.

(... and as long as you are at it... "I came across." Was it lying in the street with no names attached to it? Did it come delivered in a bolt from the blue? You are posting an image from a source, identify the source by name and author...)

An upper Darboux sum needs to be w.r.t. a certain partition. No upper Darboux sum for a function $f_n$ will be $0$, but they can be arbitrarily small: Fixing $n$, if for each $j=1,...,n$ a partition includes points $x'<x''$ s.t. $x'' - x' < \varepsilon/n$, then the associated upper Darboux sum for $f_n$ will be $< \varepsilon$.
